# Need to have a string contain code

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a simple text based game from scratch, and I'm running into a problem right away. I'm trying to create a class for events that will happen in-game to make writing the code easier. Here's what I mean:

```
class event(object):
    def __init__(self, text, trigger1, trigger2, outcome1, outcome2):
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)
        choice= input("What will you do?")
        if choice == trigger1:
               (Somehow execute outcome 1)
        if choice == trigger2:
               (Somehow execute outcome 2)
```

but I don't know how to make the outcomes contain code that I will write later, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you want `outcome 1` and `outcome 2` to be?

Comment: Do you really want `event` class objects to do all that in their `__init__()` method which is called whenever one is created? Regardless, you can execute strings in Python using `eval` and `exec` depending on what kind of code is in them (and expression or one+ statements).

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way is to use a dictionary with function objects:

```
def outcome1():
    print("Outcome 1")

def outcome2():
    print("Outcome 2")

def event(text, triggers):
    print(text)
    time.sleep(1)
    choice= input("What will you do?")
    triggers[choice]()

event("You can got west or east.", {
    "go west": outcome1,
    "go east": outcome2,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I do hope I'm understanding your question appropriately, so feel free to correct me if this isn't on target.

When you create a new instance of the class Event (and it's convention to capitalize the first character of classes).  Assign a function to the value of outcome1 and outcome2, which will be executed according to their respective triggers.

```
def outcomeFunction1():
    #Whatever you'd like to do for first outcome
    print("Hello")

def outcomeFunction2():
    #Whatever you'd like to do for second outcome
    print("Bye")

Event('text', 'trigger1', 'trigger2', outcomeFunction1(), outcomeFunction2())
```

In your class definition write:

```
if choice == trigger1:
   outcome1

elif choice == trigger2:
   outcome2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why is this in **init**? Are you really going to create new instance on every new event? To your question, if I got your question correctly, then this is code you may want to have.

```
def outcome1(text):
    print("outcome1: %s" % text)

def outcome2(text):
    print ("outcome2: %s" % text)

trigger_map = {
    trigger1 : outcome1,
    trigger2 : outcome2,
}

class event(object):
    def __init__(self, trigger_map):
        sefl._tmap = trigger_map

    def onEvent (self, text):
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)
        choice= input("What will you do?")
        return self._tmap [choice] (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but here I go...

---

The answer here depends on whether you want to have to make a new instance for every event. If you do, the code might look something like this (and as Jeremy E. pointed out, it's a good idea to capitalize the first character of classes):

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, text, question, trigger1, trigger2, outcome1, outcome2):
        self.text, self.question = text, question
        self.trigger1, self.trigger2 = trigger1, trigger2
        self.outcome1, self.outcome2 = outcome1, outcome2
    def get_choice(self):
        print(self.text)
        self.choice = input(self.question)
    def execute(self):
        if self.choice == self.trigger1:
            exec(self.outcome1)
        if self.choice == self.trigger2:
            exec(self.outcome2)
```

I used the `exec` function to execute the outcomes. I moved some of the code to different functions, leaving the `__init__` function to save the variables for the other functions. Then, you can make an instance for each event, like this:

```
room = Event("You are in a room with exits to the north and east.", "Where will you go?", "north", "east", "print('You went north.')", "print('You went east.'")
```

Notice I also added a `question` parameter, as to not force the `What will you do?` question on every event.

---

Now, if you wanted to only need one instance of the `Event` class, the code is a bit different:

```
class Event:
    def make_event(self, text, question, trigger1, trigger2, outcome1, outcome2):
        print(text)
        choice = input(question)
        if choice == trigger1:
            exec(outcome1)
        if choice == trigger2:
            exec(outcome2)
```

You can see that the code is much shorter. To create an event with this, you would do something like this (with the same example as before):

```
event = Event() # This is only needed once, at the start of the program
event.make_event("You are in a room with exits to the north and east.", "Where will you go?", "north", "east", "print('You went north.')", "print('You went east.')")
```

---

*EDIT*: You may want to remove the class definition entirely, leaving just the `make_event` function I wrote for you above.

---

You can choose between either of these class examples, or use their ideas to make a customized one. I hope I answered your question.